# How to get value after subtraction in PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, subtraction

I am creating a bakery software using PHP and MYSQL (mysqli version).I want to know how I get the subtracted value from two columns eg. 
"Price - Pay = Remaining". My problem is just fetching the subtracted data to the table from those two columns.

```
<?php
$minus = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM managment WHERE price - pay");
$sub = mysqli_fetch_assoc($minus);
?>

<tbody>
          <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['measure']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['pay']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sub['remaining']; ?></td>
          </tr>
         <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
```

What should i do...?

Comment: `price - pay` is not a condition. You have to put this in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: `SELECT *, price - payAS remaining FROM managment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><?php echo ($row['price'] - $row['pay]); ?></td>
```

Why don't you go for a simple solution like this? I guess *price* and *pay* are numbers so this will work fine for your problem.

In my sql you can do this like :

```
SELECT *, price-pay AS total From managment;
```

You will see that a new column will be "created" with the name *total* and it's values will be the subtract you are asking.

After that you just call it inside html like:

```
<td><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>
```

Comment: drop the `WHERE 1 = 1`  it's not needed.

Comment: Glad i helped. If it worked please accept it as valid answer.

Comment: in my case the column "total" gets created but it is gone again when i refresh the page of database

Comment: @Ashin Bhagat total is not a column it's an alias, so it never exists as column in your database only shows up like this in your application. It's a naming thing of an existing column not a creation of a new column inside the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (price - pay) as remaining FROM managment
```

you need to change the query. try this query and fetch data remaining data as below.

```
<?php echo $row['remaining']; ?>
```

or you can also subtract remaining as @pr1nc3 posted. above.

Answer (score 0):

Please simple use code like this :-

```
<?php
$results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT *, (price - pay) AS remaining FROM managment");
?>    
<tbody>
          <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['measure']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['pay']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['remaining']; ?></td>
          </tr>
         <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
```